# Unable to call broadcast receiver on App startup

Tags: android, xamarin, android-broadcastreceiver

Hello there i have been trying to create a broadcast receiver but i am unable to call it i.e start it from application startup here is my code please tell me that whether something is missing or not here is the things i tried until now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.testing.broacast" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application android:label="App4"></application>
<receiver android:name=".Broadcast">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
 </manifest>
```

here is my broadcast reciever

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]


public class Broadcast : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
    {

            Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            // Create your application here}

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a boot completed broadcast receiver, to which you will get a handle only after a reboot. Is that what you mean by saying `but i am unable to call it i.e start it from application startup`?

Comment: @MikeM.      hello mike i am starting my application atleast once so that i can start broadcast reciever

Comment: @Skynet no i want to start my service as soon as my application is once started like on tap and it should run continously on the back

Comment: Oh, OK. I guess I'm not as familiar with Xamarin's manifest structure as I thought. :-)

Comment: @MikeM. its almost same

Comment: Yeah, but apparently you don't have to list `<activity>` elements, yes?

Comment: @MikeM.you have to list activity elements into manifest

Comment: The manifest is created out of your Attributes. So the `[Intent-Filter]` Attribute creates the `<intent-filter>` tag

Comment: @Matt am i missing something here?

Comment: OK, but then how are you launching your app without an `Activity`?

Comment: @MikeM. i have a main activity

Comment: I'm just really confused now, 'cause there's not one listed in your manifest. Anyway, if the requirements for Xamarin's manifest are like those of the Java SDK, then the `<receiver>` element needs to be inside the `<application>` tags. Also, from your comments, I'm not sure if a boot Receiver is what you want. A boot Receiver runs when the device boots up, not when your app launches.

Comment: @MikeM.oh i see than what to do if i want to launch the reciever when app starts?

Comment: If you just want to start a `Service` when you launch your app, you don't need a Receiver for that. You can start the `Service` in either your `Application`'s `OnCreate()` method, or an `Activity`s `OnCreate()`.

Comment: @MikeM. but i dont want it to be  terminated even if the app is closed or terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works on my device

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
public class Broadcast : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

The difference is `[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]`

Also I did not need to put the `receiver` tag in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Did you try with adb?
`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p {package-name}`

Comment: i am using xamarin i dont think i can do this

Comment: Sure you can, just did the same. If you use Visual Studio click the 4th icon in android toolbar ;)

Comment: yes i am using visual studio and thanks let me try there

Comment: i did run the command it is saying
Broadcast Completed:results 0

Comment: This is fine. When I do this, I can see "Hello" on my screen. Same on your device?

Comment: No Matt i am not seeing the toast on my screen :( i dont know why i have been stuck on this problem for two days dont know what i am doing wrong please help!

Comment: Yes i did see the toast :) thanks for the help Sir can you please tell me that when i open the settings then i didnt see the process of my application running is that okay? does this mean that still my application process is runing on the backend?